# How can I get the precision of top 5 topics through my classifier?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

I have 22465 test documents which I am classifying into 88 different topics. 
I am using predict_proba to get the top 5 predicted topics. How can I then print the precision of these 5 topics?

For accuracy, this is what I am doing:

```
model1 = LogisticRegression()
model1 = model1.fit(matrix, labels)

y_train_pred = model1.predict_log_proba(matrix_test)
order=np.argsort(y_train_pred, axis=1)
print(order[:,-5:]) #gives top 5 probabilities

n=model1.classes_[order[:, -5:]]
```

For Accuracy

```
z=0
for x, y in zip(label_tmp_test, n):
    if x in y:
        z=z+1
print(z)
print(z/22465) #This gives me the accuracy by considering top 5 topics
```

How can I find precision of the top 5 topics in the same manner? Scikit metrics refuses to work with

```
q=model1.predict(mat_tmp_test)
print(metrics.precision_score(n, q))
```

Answer (score 0):

IN you methodology precision is nearly the same - you simply focus on a particular label (as precision is per-label metric), lets say you calculate precision for label L:

```
TP = 0.
FP = 0.
for x, y in zip(label_tmp_test, n):

    if x == L: # this is the label we are interested in
        if L in y: # correct prediction is among selected ones
            TP = TP + 1 # we get one more true positive instance

    else: # this is some other label
        if L in y: # if we predicted that this is a particular label
            FP = FP + 1 # we have created another false positive

print(TP / (TP + FP))
```

Now if you need "general" precision - you would usually average per-label precisions. For obvious reasons you need lots of labels for these kind of measures to make sense.